# How to draw Pimary Key and Foreign Key RelationShip in MS VISIO

Tags: visio

I am Drawing some ER Diagram for my application and need to draw primary and foreign key relationship between given entity but not find out any solution which works for me, Please if any one knows help me.

Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

Create a foreign key relationship with the Relationship tool

I have Spent Some Time And Got Solution:

[Follow Below Link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/visio-help/create-a-foreign-key-relationship-with-the-connector-tool-HP001208397.aspx)